# Meteor Collection empty in template

Tags: meteor, collections

I'm in the early stages of a Meteor project with all default packages present, including autopublish. Adding a Collection `Notes` to my project worked fine and displayed as expected.

When I added a second Collection. `Tags`, replicating the same pattern, it is always empty.

So I need some pointers what to watch out for. I've read e.g. [David Weldons list of common mistakes](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards) but found no clue there.

There are two templates displaying two Collections, one is displaying fine, the other is not.

The Collections are declared exactly the same:

```
export const Tags = new Mongo.Collection('Tags');
export const Notes = new Mongo.Collection('Notes');
```

They are displayed by similar, simple, templates, which are referenced in my html:

```
<body>
  <div>
    {{#each tags}}
      {{> tag}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
  <div>
    {{#each notes}}
      {{> note}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</body>
```

And the template helpers are also identical:

```
Template.body.helpers({
  notes() {
    return Notes.find({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1}});
  },
  tags() {
    let t = Tags.find({});
    return t;
  },
});
```

If I break after `let t =...` then `t.fetch()` gives an empty array. (`meteor mongo: db.Tags.find()` is *not* empty...)

Returning an array from the `tags()`-helper displays that data correctly, so it is obviously something I miss with the `Tags`-collection.

Might this be a case of timing? I thought that helpers are reactive and as such should take care of such things. Or do I need to look into explicit subscriptions, `iron:router` and `waitOn`?

*FIX:*

As indicated by @Jankapunkt, I had forgotten to add the collection to the server side startup.

Comment: Which collection is not displaying? And what do you mean by "not displaying find"? Does it mean `console.log(NameOfCollection.find())` returns no data or nothing is rendered on the screen?

Comment: With a break after `let t =...` then `t.fetch()` gives an empty array.

Comment: Do you import `Tags` on startup to both server and client?

Comment: Thanks, @Jankapunkt, that was it. Turn your comment into an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to successfully autopublish your mongo collection's data to your clients, you need to import the collection both to server and client (preferably on startup).

**Example**

*imports/MyCollection.js*

```
export const MyCollection = new Mongo.Collection('mycollection');
```

*server/main.js*

```
import { MyCollection } from '../imports/MyCollection';
```

*client/main.js*

```
import { MyCollection } from '../imports/MyCollection';
```

If you remove the `autopublish` package you will however need to add publications on the server side and subscriptions on the client side.

Further readings:

https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html

https://guide.meteor.com/collections.html

Comment: I suppose that means that a client side-only `new Collection('name')` (even with the "name") just creates the minimongo collection but can't connect to a server side corresponding collection. I might have expected an error in such situations, but perhaps that's not possible.

Comment: I think it is by purpose that it allows you to create different collections of the same name on server and client. I just don't have a use case right now.